# Generate ISO from installed system

Tags: linux, virtualization, proxmox

As part of my infrastructure I have many Virtual Machines running different Linux distros, under Proxmox using OpenVz.

My problem is that I need to export into a personalized installable ISOs some of the VMs I have, (installable snapshots of the current state of the VMs), some of them are running `Ubuntu`, some of them `CentOS`, so my question is:

1. Is there a way I can do this aware of the OS the VM is running?
2. Exporting VMs to ISOs the way I just explained is the way to go or
   is there any other approach?

I'm open to any advice from those how has experience with this subject even if I have to setup different Virt. Technology to host the VMs.

Comment: Have you tried rsync instead of iso?

Comment: I would like if possible to take the generated ISO, mount it on anther PC and install the snapshot of the VM generated, the same it does the Proxmox people with their ISO, when you install Proxmox it comes pre-configured system, how will I be able to do this with rsync?

Comment: I don't know how ISOs are deployed. If it simply unpacked then rsync is enough (you can convert output to iso). If it is writtend directly to disk then better would be dd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do, you might have different choice : did you think about clonezilla ? Simple tool to clone any machine (virtual or physical).

Also if you just need to install several VM with the same configuration, VM templating is the right choice : https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/VM_Templates_and_Clones

Answer (score 0):

Any bootable distributon with a dd image of your base system.